# Is there a PHP function to htmlspecialchars() everything except for certain tags?

Tags: php, tags, html-escape-characters

It would be nice if I could call `my_escape($text, '<p><b><i>')` that escapes everything except all `<p>`, `<b>` and `<i>` tags. I'm looking for a generic solution where I can specify an arbitrary set of tags. Does this exist? If not what's the best approach to implement it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

in htmlspecialchars function it converts html tags to

```
& to &amp;
" to &quot;
' to &#039;
< to &lt;
> to &gt;
```

after convert you can do reverse to decode

```
<?php
$test="<p><b><a>Test</b></a></p>";

$test = htmlspecialchars($test);

$test = str_replace("&lt;p&gt;", "<p>", $test);
$test = str_replace("&lt;i&gt;", "<i>", $test);
$test = str_replace("&lt;b&gt;", "<b>", $test);
$test = str_replace("&lt;/b&gt;", "</b>", $test);
$test = str_replace("&lt;/i&gt;", "</i>", $test);
$test = str_replace("&lt;/p&gt;", "</p>", $test);

echo $test;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to do something like this

```
// Add placeholders
$search = array('<p>', '<b>');
$replace = array("\ap\a", "\ab\a");
$text = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);

$text = htmlspecialchars($text);

// Put it all back together
$text = str_replace($replace, $search, $text);
```

It would be best to use a regular expression, but that is a lot more explaining.

Comment: If you're working on an editor, I'd look at SCEditor or similar.

Comment: Yeah, though that's unlikely, I'd use a different place holder like `\a`.

Comment: what's `\a`? If I `echo` `"\a"` it's just `\a`.

Comment: \a is the bell/beep character. http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Comment: I would recommend using something more like what @Nsk answered.

Comment: you can do the reverse after using htmlspecialchars function @Joshua Dickerson like str_replace("&lt;p&gt;", "<p>", $text)